# How to delete a long list of sites from Webmaster Tools?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, google-search, analytics

I have 8 properties set for deletion or pending.

I unlinked Google Analytics, checked all the sites and always get a 404 response.

Yet somehow certain domain names are still in Google search or Cache.

Sorry if I'm way off here. Just need guidance.

Comment: It sounds like you want to remove these sites from Google's index - not simply from Search Console (formerly "Webmaster Tools")? Google Search Console is primarily a tool for reporting tool - simply removing a property from Search Console will not do anything to remove the site from Google's index.

Comment: @w3dk  I just checked on my sites and they are all indeed gone!  Even out of search.   Checked all the tools and resources as well.

Comment: I'm closing this question because you indicate in the comments that the problem solved itself just by waiting.

Comment: I re-opened this.  It is still a problem?

Comment: So others could benefit from what you figured out maybe you could post what you figured out as an answer.

Comment: To actually delete the sites it is needed to go to my Google analytics account.  Go to the Admin section and look up all the sites analytics were indexing and analyzing. There is a lot to it.  So you have to seperate all sites from analytics not just Google search console. @MrWhite

Comment: It was an issue once again yes.  Dig through analytics and other anlaytic products its all linked. Also the search console on Google dev site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the properties from Google's index, you would first have to add the properties again in your Webmaster account, then go to each of the sites and [request removal of the whole site](https://support.google.com/websearch/troubleshooter/3111061?hl=en&visit_id=1-636342251362378353-2529438139&rd=1).

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/feeds/question/104525